# Headers in nextjs how to edit them and return them in route handlers

Tags: reactjs, typescript, download, router, ytdl

I have the following code in a route handler

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

import ytdl from "ytdl-core";

export async function POST(request: NextRequest){
    try {
        const {url_video, formatArchive, quality} = await request.json()
        const response = NextResponse.next()
        const title = (await ytdl.getInfo(url_video)).player_response.videoDetails
        
        if(!url_video){
            return NextResponse.json({error: "Url não inserida"})
        }
        
        if(!quality){
            return NextResponse.json({error: "Formato do arquivo não inserido"})
        }

        if(formatArchive == "video"){
            const video = ytdl(url_video, {filter: format => format.qualityLabel === quality})
            response.headers.set(`Content-Disposition`, `attachment; filename=${title}.mp4`);
            response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'video/mp4');
            video.pipe(response)
            return
        }

        const video = ytdl(url_video, {filter: format => format.audioBitrate === quality})
        response.headers.set(`Content-Disposition`, `attachment; filename=${title}.mp3`);
        response.headers.set('Content-Type', 'audio/mpeg');
        video.pipe(response)
    } catch (error) {
        return NextResponse.json({error: `Erro no download ${error}`}, {status: 500})
    }
}
```

This code even somehow downloads the file, however, it doesn't download in the right size, and it happens that when I listen to the file, it appears that the file is corrupted, because a 120kbps mp3 file it downloads in 1kb.
In the video.pipe part, it gives this error:
`This code even somehow downloads the file, however, it doesn't download in the right size, and it happens that when I listen to the file, it appears that the file is corrupted, because a 120kbps mp3 file it downloads in 1kb`, why would it be? because this is a typing error, I don't know if that's why, but even with this error, the code runs perfectly.